postgreSQL recursive query return wrong result
I use postgresql version 11
I want to find all unit which are under specific unit using  query recursive .
the table unit have this columns : id,parentid,status,active
table unitlang : name,lang
I try with this code to find all unit under 'UN-25'
but it return also unit which the id contain 'UN-25' and not under 'UN-25'
select id from unit where id in (
  
   select distinct id    

   from    
   (WITH RECURSIVE tree    
   AS    
   (    
     SELECT    
         ul.name as node_name, unit.id, unit.parentid as parent_id,  
     cast(unit.id AS text) AS path,unit.status as status,unit.active as active    
      FROM unit    
     left outer join unitlang ul on ul.unit_id=unit.id and ul.lang = 'EN'   
     WHERE unit.parentid IS NULL  
     and unit.status='1'     

       UNION    
      SELECT    
          node_name, f1.id, f1.parentid,cast(tree.path || ',' || f1.id AS text) AS path,f1.status as status,f1.active as active    
      FROM    
         tree    
         JOIN unit f1 ON f1.parentid = tree.id    
        where f1.status='1'   
    )    
   SELECT id, node_name, parent_id, node_name, path FROM tree ORDER BY path) liste    
   where position('UN-25' in path)<>0 and POSITION(id in path)>=POSITION('UN-25' in path)    
  
  )

Thank you for your help
Updated :
this is an example :
unit :
id       parentid 

UN-25    
UN-30    UN-25
UN-31    UN-25
UN-40    UN-30
UN-41    UN-30
UN-255   UN-10
UN-85    UN-10

so the correct resultat to display UN-25 and its children should be
UN-25 , UN-30 ,UN-31 ,UN-40 , UN-41   but it display also UN-255
because UN-255  contain UN-25
I want only to display UN-25 and it's children (UN-25 , UN-30 ,UN-31 ,UN-40 , UN-41
)

Please demo the problem using a fiddle. Should be quite easy to fix, if we can see the issue.

thank you for your response, I have updated my question with a detailed example

You can use a recursive CTE, as in:
with recursive
n as (
  select * from unit where id = 'UN-25'
 union all
  select u.* from n join unit u on u.parentid = n.id
)
select * from n;

Result:
 id     parentid 
 ------ -------- 
 UN-25  null     
 UN-30  UN-25    
 UN-31  UN-25    
 UN-40  UN-30    
 UN-41  UN-30    

See running example at db<>fiddle.
